# Unable to find error resolution Httpclient service not registered

Tags: blazor

I discover Blazor last week, and just the idea of it is fascinating to me I really like how it is structure or at least what I have seemed so far, I think I got grasp of most of what I have read, so I decide to do  small Rss reader as a first test demo app, I basically based it on this tutorial but only the bare minimal function-ability, like only getting one type of post instead of all suggested on the tutorial, the post was made last year so of course it is not going to be a copy and paste situation, after a couple of days on reading on Blazor I start but run into a weird error and 2 days of googling have not helped me resolve it yet, I was hoping anyone could here, sorry if my grammar is not the best, I'm very aware of it :) I do hope it is understandable.
[image][image]

[image]

```
@page "/latestposts"
@using Projectname.Shared.Models
@using System.Net.Http;
@inject HttpClient Http

<h4>C# Corner Latest Posts</h4>

@if (feeds == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    counter = 0;
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sl.No.</th>
                <th>Post Title (With Link)</th>
                <th>Post Type</th>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th>Publish Date</th>
                <th>Author</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var feed in feeds)
            {
                counter++;
                <tr>
                    <td>@counter</td>
                    <td><NavLink href=@feed.Link target="_blank">@feed.Title</NavLink></td>
                    <td>@feed.FeedType</td>
                    <td>@feed.Content</td>
                    <td>@feed.PublishDate</td>
                    <td>@feed.Author</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
@functions {
    Feed[] feeds;
    int counter;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        feeds = null;
        feeds = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Feed[]>("/api/feeds/latestposts");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is injected out of the box on blazor hosted. On server side you don't need Rest requests because the backend is in the same place as frond end. Just calling a local function is enough.

Any case, if you need an Http client, for example to go to another site, I suggest to you to use [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0):

Basic Usage:

1. Install `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` from NuGet.
2. Add to services:

   ```
   services.AddHttpClient();
   // builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); (on wasm)
   ```
3. Get from DI:

   ```
   @inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory
   ```
4. Make request:

   ```
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
       "https://farm/cowsservice");
   request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
   request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
   var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

   var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
       using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
       MyCows = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
           <IEnumerable<Cow>>(responseStream);
   }
   else
   {
       GetBranchesError = true;
       MyCows = Array.Empty<Cow>();
   }
   ```

This is [Daniel Roth (Blazor product manager) talking about this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1588#issuecomment-515097675):

> On the server IHttpClientFactory provides a number of benefits for making general HTTP requests that are outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests.
>
> The HttpClient provided for Blazor WebAssembly Apps is bit more specialized and is specifically configured for making requests back to the server of origin.

Of course, you can also use `HttpClient` adding it to services via DI:

```
services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
```